# Django prevent caching view if user is logged in

Tags: django, http-caching

My visitors get a cached version of the page from Varnish.
I would like the admin user to see the current version of the page all times.
This way, all changes are directly visible.

Does someting like that exist?
I'm aware of the `@never_cache` decorator.
I'm looking for something like that, only if the user is not logged in.

Bonus points if it works with Django-CMS!

Comment: Surely this is a Varnish question, not a Django one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out there is something like:

```
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True
```

That should work for most web sites, if there is no distinction between users and staff members.

To explicitly send a `Cache-Control` header for staff members, some middleware can be written (which also varies on `Cookie` header sadly).

Comment: This option was deprecated and is removed in current Django versions.

Answer (score 12):

I assumed that you're using cache decorators. The code below is a decorator that returns a view decorated with another decorator (i.e. `cache_page`) only if user is not admin. So admin will always get the non-decorated (non-cached) page, and other users will get decorated (so possibly cached) page. It works with all possible decorators (not only with the `cache_page`).

```
def conditional_cache(decorator):
    """ Returns decorated view if user is not admin. Un-decorated otherwise """

    def _decorator(view):

        decorated_view = decorator(view)  # This holds the view with cache decorator

        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):

            if request.user.is_staff:     # If user is staff
                return view(request, *args, **kwargs)  # view without @cache
            else:
                return decorated_view(request, *args, **kwargs) # view with @cache

        return _view

    return _decorator
```

To use it, instead of typical syntax:

```
@cache_page(123)
def testview(request):
    (...)
```

use:

```
@conditional_cache(decorator=cache_page(123))  # The argument is what you usually do with views, but without the @
def testview(request):
    (...)
```

Comment: Works well for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY` [is removed in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/)

Instead, [vary headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers) can be used and more specifically the decorator `vary_on_cookie`.

This means that a separate cache is kept according to the cookie of each user.

Logged in users have a cookie as opposed to not logged in ones and therefore different caches are created per cookie session. What follows is my implemetation.

`urls.py`  entry:

```
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_cookie
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

...
    url(
            r'^$',
            cache_page(60 * 1440, cache='disk')(vary_on_cookie(MyCbvView.as_view())),
            name='view-name',
        ),
...
```